# Using DISTINCT based on a single column in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

This question tends to come up a lot, but I haven't quite found an answer that makes sense to me or is applicable.

Consider this table:

```
order_id   user_id   order_date
1           1        2012-01-01
1           1        2012-01-15
2           2        2012-01-15
2           2        2012-01-20
2           2        2012-01-25
3           2        2012-01-15
3           2        2012-01-16
4           2        2012-01-15
4           2        2012-01-16
```

I want to retrieve (order_id, user_id) where the user_id is distinct, based on some conditions on the order_date.

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT user_id, order_id, MAX(order_date) FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING
MAX(order_date) < '2012-01-20'
```

Which returns

```
user_id   order_id   MAX(order_date)
1          1         2012-01-15
2          3         2012-01-16
2          4         2012-01-16
```

However, I want this result set to also group on on user_id, based on the maximum order_id. I want:

```
user_id   order_id   MAX(order_date)
1          1         2012-01-15
2          4         2012-01-16
```

How can I do a GROUP BY based on order_id, and then subsequently group (or possibly distinct, if I drop the requirement of having the MAX order_id) on user_id?

Comment: Does the table have a primary key? Without a unique way of identifying the interesting row, it's quite a bit harder.

Comment: Sure, we can add a generic "id" for each row as a primary key. (This example is a simplification of the full query which joins across multiple tables, but yes, we can primary key this baby.)

Comment: Hey poundifdef, remember if your question has been answered, then you should select an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one column specified for `GROUP BY` try this:

```
SELECT user_id, order_id, MAX(order_date) FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id, user_id
HAVING
MAX(order_date) < '2012-01-20'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a no-go: `GROUP BY order_id, user_id` groups by the unique combination of order and user IDs, rather than first grouping by order_id, and then subsequently by user_id.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what you meant. You will need to use a nested query to achieve that sequential grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.order_id, MAX(o.user_id) AS MaxUserId, q.MaxOrderDate
    FROM orders o
        INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, MAX(order_date) AS MaxOrderDate
                        FROM orders
                        GROUP BY order_id
                        HAVING MAX(order_date) < '2012-01-20') q
            ON o.order_id= q.order_id
                AND o.order_date = q.MaxOrderDate
   GROUP BY o.order_id, q.MaxOrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
SELECT S1.user_id, S1.order_id, S1.maxDate from
    (SELECT o1.user_id, o1.order_id, MAX(o1.order_date) maxDate FROM o1
    GROUP BY o1.order_id
    HAVING MAX(o1.order_date) < '2012-01-20') S1
LEFT JOIN o2 ON (S1.user_id = o2.user_id AND S1.order_id < o2.order_id)
WHERE (o2.order_id IS null)
```

Note: `o1` and `o2` are both the orders table

This should work as expected or I might have misunderstood the requirements. Here is an [example](http://sqlize.com/zc01d2AM93)