# Two sql query as one

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

There are two sql queries, I want to write as one query.
the second query display the count of distinct records where action_text like '%STAFF%'.
I tried using UNION but It did not work.

```
select date(dated) date_ord,
count(DISTINCT order_number) as orders_placed, 
sum(case when action_text like '%STAFF%' then 1 else 0 end) AS orders_staff,
sum(case when action_text in (
                'CBA Capture attempt',
                'GCO Capture attempt',
                'PPP Capture',
                'PPE Capture',
                'Staff CC capture',
                'Web CC capture',
                'Staff Finance WIRE authorized',
                'Staff Finance PO authorized',
                'Staff Finance COD authorized',
                'Authorized The CPIC') then 1 else 0 end)     AS     orders_manuallycaptured
 from stats.sales_actions
 group by date_ord 
 order by dated desc


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) as unique_orderstouched,
date(dated) date_ords
FROM sales_actions
WHERE action_text like '%STAFF%' 
group by date_ords 
order by dated desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only new column in the second query is `COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) ... WHERE action_text LIKE '%STAFF%'`.

Then you can just add in a `COUNT(DISTINCT IF(action-text LIKE '%STAFF%',order_number,NULL)) as unique_orderstouched` to your original query.

(Also I assume the table `stats.sales_actions` in your first query is the same as the table `sales_actions` in your second query?).

You'd end up with:

```
select date(dated) date_ord,
count(DISTINCT order_number) as orders_placed, 
sum(case when action_text like '%STAFF%' then 1 else 0 end) AS orders_staff,
sum(case when action_text in (
                'CBA Capture attempt',
                'GCO Capture attempt',
                'PPP Capture',
                'PPE Capture',
                'Staff CC capture',
                'Web CC capture',
                'Staff Finance WIRE authorized',
                'Staff Finance PO authorized',
                'Staff Finance COD authorized',
                'Authorized The CPIC') then 1 else 0 end) AS orders_manuallycaptured,
-- new line follows
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(action-text LIKE '%STAFF%',order_number,NULL)) 
   AS unique_orderstouched
 from stats.sales_actions
 group by date_ord 
 order by dated desc
```

The `COUNT( DISTINCT IF( condition, order_number, NULL ) )` is like saying `COUNT( DISTINCT order_number ) ... WHERE <condition>` -- you can also think of it as being like your `SUM( CASE WHEN condition THEN 1 ELSE 0)`, but with a `DISTINCT` in it.

Comment: Date
 Orders
Placed Orders
Touched Orders manually
captured Unique Orders
touched 
2012-02-03 329 162 77 135 
2012-02-02 299 148 70 122 
2012-02-01 340 169 102 156 
2012-01-31 271 143 78 126 
2012-01-30 436 211 129 187 
2012-01-27 275 138 66 112 
2012-01-26 318 150 87 128 
2012-01-25 297 145 91 152 
2012-01-24 163 77 60 87

Answer (score 0):

If you do a union the columns you select need to be the same between the two queries. You need to have the same number of columns, same data types, and they need to be in the same order.  In the first query you are selecting four columns and the second query only two.

Comment: Ok then what could be the soultion then?

Comment: The first step to the solution is that you edit your answer adding an example of the result you're expecting to get

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you are trying to do with your query?

Comment: where 1st col is date,2nd orders_placed,3rd orders_staff,4th orders_manuallycaptured, 5th unique_orderstouched

Comment: If 1st col is date, then why your second query does a count()? That results in a number not a date. Please, write the result (including column names!) you're expecting with 4 or 5 rows so that we can understand what you expected result is. Example of a well-written question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133068/using-distinct-based-on-a-single-column-in-group-by/9138907